# SonarQube compatibility with Jenkins

Tags: sonarqube

We are using sonarqube(5.1.2)  and jenkins(2.51) to run code analysis. Now we are planning to upgrade sonarqube to version 5.6.4.

Do we also need to upgrade Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to.
Sonar is an independent tool, Jenkins is responsible only for running maven/gradle script, that will 'feed' sonar with data. Just make sure you have same credentials for new sonar and it should be fine.

You could consider upgrading Sonar plugin version also.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether the sonar plugin installed in Jenkins will support the new Sonarqube version else you will have to upgrade the plugin.